# Function to compare contents of variant fails to compile

Tags: c++, templates, boost-variant, equality-operator

In my projects I'm using `boost-variant` exhaustively. Hence, for my unit tests I need to check the contents of a variant against a certain `T` with a certain content `t`.

So I deviced the function `cmpVariant` for this sole purpose and to remove clutter from my unit tests.

In some cases the type `T` is not equipped with an `operator==`, so that the user might pass a function satisfying the *EqualityCompare Requirement* (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/EqualityComparable)

Now for some obscure reason the following code fails to compile. It says, that there is no matching function?

**Clang 6.0.1 Compiler Error**

```
prog.cc:22:5: error: no matching function for call to 'cmpVariant'
    cmpVariant(number, 3.2, lambdaEquiv); // Fails!
    ^~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:6:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<bool (const type-parameter-0-1 &, const type-parameter-0-1 &)>' against '(lambda at prog.cc:19:24)'
bool cmpVariant(
     ^
1 error generated.
```

Does anyone knows why?

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <functional>

template<typename V, typename T>
bool cmpVariant(
    const V& variant,
    const T& t,
    const std::function<bool(const T& u, const T& v)>& equiv = [](const T& u, const T& v) {return u == v; })
{
    if (variant.type() != typeid(t)) return false;
    auto v = boost::get<T>(variant);
    return equiv(v, t);
}

int main(int, char**) {
    boost::variant<double, int> number{ 3.2 };
    cmpVariant(number, 3.2);
    auto lambdaEquiv = [](const double& x, const double& y) { return x == y; };
    std::function<bool(const double&, const double&)> equiv = lambdaEquiv;
    cmpVariant(number, 3.2, equiv); // Works!
    cmpVariant(number, 3.2, lambdaEquiv); // Fails!
}
```

Comment: You should post error message here.

Comment: @VTT: Error Messages are unfortunately in German and are hard to translate. Maybe it is more suitable to include a live-code?

Comment: @Aleph0 Are you using MSVC? You can install English language pack as well to get English messages, switching temporarily to if needed (or permanently, I always considered English error messages superior to German equivalents anyway...).

Comment: @Aconcagua: I'll try, but it takes a while.

Comment: Even the error ID is better than nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is not able to match the lambda to the function parameter type. You can fix this by explicitly instantiating the function call:

```
cmpVariant<boost::variant<double, int>, double>(number, 3.2, equiv);
```

This is clearly a bit wordy, so here is another possibility changing your function declaration to

```
template<typename V, typename T, typename Fct = std::function<bool(const T& u, const T& v)>>
bool cmpVariant(
    const V& variant,
    const T& t,
    Fct&& f = [](const T& u, const T& v) {return u == v; })
{ /* Same as before. */ }
```

which can be called like this

```
cmpVariant(number, 3.2, equiv); // Type deduction works now.
```

An improvement suggested by @DanielLangr in the comments is to employ [`std::equal_to`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/equal_to).

```
template<typename V, typename T, typename Fct = std::equal_to<T>>
bool cmpVariant(
      const V& variant,
      const T& t,
      Fct&& f = std::equal_to<T>{})
{ /* Again, same as before. */ }
```

One advantage here is to get rid of `std::function` and its often unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Many thanks for your solution. I also found a possible why, by transforming the lambda explicitly into an `std::function`. Also thanks for thorough explanation.

Comment: You can you can use `std::equal_to` instead of defining lambda that just compares with `==`.

Comment: Yours solution works and is awesome. I need some time to digest it. Was never aware of `std::equal_to` either.

Comment: @DanielLangr Thanks for the hint, I'll adjust the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The way comparator argument is accepted makes deduction problematic, so you may want to change comparator into template parameter (possibly avoiding construction of heavy `std::function` object ):

```
template<typename T> class t_EquilityComparator
{
    public: bool operator ()(const T& u, const T& v) const { return u == v; }
};

template<typename V, typename T, typename Comparator = t_EquilityComparator<T>>
bool cmpVariant(
    const V& variant,
    const T& t,
    const Comparator & equiv = Comparator{})
{
    if (variant.type() != typeid(t)) return false;
    auto v = boost::get<T>(variant);
    return equiv(v, t);
}

int main(int, char**) {
    boost::variant<double, int> number{ 3.2 };
    cmpVariant(number, 3.2);
    auto equiv = [](const double& x, const double& y) { return x == y; };
    cmpVariant(number, 3.2, equiv); // This line fails to compile! Why?
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IoWmEYxNgncbHaMt)

Comment: Also thanks. Too bad one can only mark one solution as the best. Give it to lubgr, as he fast seconds faster. :-(